# What happens to Narek?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-picard

So, maybe I was crying too much and missed it, but did season 1 of ST:Picard really end without saying anything whatsoever about what happens to Narek?

> Does he know that his sister is (likely) dead?

But really, just: what does he do? Where does he go?

> I'm pretty sure he's still alive, but maybe there was a blink-and-you'll-miss-it scene where the synths kill him? Or something?

Note that I'm asking **specifically about episode 10 of season 1**. In "Et in Arcadia Ego Part 2", what happens to Narek? Don't go bringing season 2 (or 28) into this.

Comment: I don't follow the series but from a quick glance doesn't that question fall into the "future works policy" kind of close-worthy questions?

Comment: @Jenayah - ST-PIC has ended its first season. Narek's fate in that adventure should have been decided one way or the other by now.

Comment: @Jeeped Surprisingly, after some point in the last episode he just "disappears" and it's not known what happens to him. I guess his scenes were cut for time. However, probably this question will be answered in the new season, hence I'm VTC under the future works policy.

Comment: @Rebel-Scum: Except I couldn't care less what happens to Narek in season 2, or season 342. I want to know what  happens to him in the last episode  of season 1. ***NOT*** in the future. ***NOW***.

Comment: "I want to know what happens to him in the last episode of season 1" We don't know what happened to him as it's not shown on screen, hence any answer is going to be, by definition, opinion based. This might help: https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5187/should-questions-about-future-works-be-closed-as-primarily-opinion-based

Comment: @Rebel-Scum: “we don’t know” is a perfectly valid answer. At least as of the current edit the question is whether it was shown what happened to this character in a particular episode, and if so, what. This has a clear answer and is not about future works.

Comment: In my idealized world, someone will re-watch the episode and describe for me exactly when we last see Narek, what he's doing, what others are saying, etc.

Answer (score 7):

According to Michael Chabon, one of the show's producers, Narek's scene which would show him

> being taken into Federation custody,

was indeed cut at the editorial process. He clarified this and other things in a social media platform AMA session, with everything being compiled by TrekMovie [here](https://trekmovie.com/2020/03/28/michael-chabon-answers-fan-questions-about-star-trek-picard-finale-loose-ends-season-two-and-more/). The quote goes as follows:

> **Chabon**: Yeah. Narek. We know, we know. A casualty of the editorial process, alas. The intention was for him to be taken into Federation custody.

So, this is the closest we get to a canon answer about Narek's fate at the moment.